# How can I watch less file changes after ejecting create react app

Tags: webpack, less, create-react-app

Recently, I've created a react project using `create-react-app` and I've ejected it in order to customise the project. And then I want to add support for `Less` so I added the following code in `webpack.config.dev.js` before the `test: /\.css$/` part.

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    // activate source maps via loader query
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: '' } },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins() {
            return [
              require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 4 versions'] }),
            ];
          },
        },
      },
      { loader: 'less-loader', options: { sourceMap: '' } },
    ],
  }),
},
```

The problem is, with this configuration, whenever a less file changes, the application doesn't compile the less file automatically. Only when I change a css or js file will the app recompile the changes in less files.

It seems that the `create-react-app` webpack configuration doesn't watch changes of less files. I've been searching for a long time and there are only answers about how to watch `Less` without eject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ejected the Create React App, you should end up having two `webpack.config` files in the `./config` directory: `webpack.config.prod.js` and `webpack.config.dev.js`.

Beware: `ExtractTextPlugin` is defined in the prod config file, not in the dev one.

I managed to use less by installing both `less` and `less-loader`

```
npm install --save-dev less less-loader
```

Then, in `webpack.config.dev.js`, duplicate the rule used for CSS (`{test: /\.css$/, ...}`). Then in one of those rules, change the test value to `test: /\.less$/` and add `require.resolve('less-loader')` at the end of its `use` array.

It works for me and watches less files.